# Why using "yo polymer" with yeoman don't create the bower folder with webcomponent folder?

Tags: node.js, polymer-1.0, yeoman-generator

I'm having this problem, I'm trying to create my polymer project using Yeoman. The problem is when the command finish it is successfully but when I go to the folder I found that the folder `bower_components` were not created in the project.

I checked and everything is installed, "npm", "bower", "yeoman" and the "polymer generator"

> Yeoman Doctor Running sanity checks on your system
>
> ✔ Global configuration file is valid ✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
>   ✔ Node.js version ✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory ✔ No
>   .yo-rc.json file in home directory ✔ npm version
>
> Everything looks all right!

### bower.json file

```
{
  "name": "polymer-starter-kit",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "iron-elements": "PolymerElements/iron-elements#^1.0.0",
    "neon-elements": "PolymerElements/neon-elements#^1.0.0",
    "page": "visionmedia/page.js#~1.6.4",
    "paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#^1.0.1",
    "platinum-elements": "PolymerElements/platinum-elements#^1.1.0",
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "ignore": []
}
```

these are the folders and files inside the project folder:

- CONTRIBUTING.md
- README.md
- bower.json
- node_modules
- tasks
- LICENSE.md
- app
- gulpfile.js
- package.json
- travis-runner.sh

If you see I'm running the command `yo doctor`and everything looks all right.

### Files and Folders created in the project folder:

```
create bower.json
   create package.json
   create app/cache-config.json
   create app/elements/elements.html
   create app/elements/my-greeting/my-greeting.html
   create app/elements/my-list/my-list.html
   create app/elements/routing.html
   create app/favicon.ico
   create app/images/touch/apple-touch-icon.png
   create app/images/touch/chrome-splashscreen-icon-384x384.png
   create app/images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png
   create app/images/touch/icon-128x128.png
   create app/images/touch/icon-512x512.png
   create app/images/touch/icon-72x72.png
   create app/images/touch/icon-96x96.png
   create app/images/touch/ms-icon-144x144.png
   create app/images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png
   create app/index.html
   create app/manifest.json
   create app/robots.txt
   create app/scripts/app.js
   create app/styles/app-theme.html
   create app/styles/main.css
   create app/styles/shared-styles.html
   create app/sw-import.js
   create CONTRIBUTING.md
   create LICENSE.md
   create README.md
   create tasks/ensure-files.js
   create travis-runner.sh
   create .bowerrc
   create .editorconfig
   create .gitattributes
   create .travis.yml
   create .gitignore
   create gulpfile.js
   create wct.conf.js
   create app/test/index.html
   create app/test/my-greeting-basic.html
   create app/test/my-list-basic.html
```

Please any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `bower install` in your project root in order to get the `bower_components` directory. Normally, Yeoman generators runs this command for you after setup, but it looks like you have to run it yourself manually.

This will install all dependencies listed in `bower.json` into the directory `bower_components`.

Comment: Thanks so much, you're right, I knew about bower install but I was confident that yeoman run this for me. I appreciate your help

Comment: I run bower install after the yo polymer and it didn't create the bower-component folder, any other idea?

Comment: And you ran it in the same directory the `bower.json`-file is located?

Comment: yes I ran the command in the same folder where I ran the yo polymer command.

Comment: That's not what I asked though, I asked if you ran it in the same folder where your `bower.json`-file is located.

Comment: Yes I did, in my post I put the files inside the project folder and the bower.json is there and I ran into this folder

Comment: And your `.bowerrc`-file? Is it configured to another directory? Please read this: http://bower.io/docs/config/

Comment: Thanks for your time, about this file I didn't change anything, I just make `yo polymer` and in the same folder ran the `bower install`

Comment: In the project folder I don't have the file `.bowerrc`

Comment: You'll have to reach out to the authors of the generator or look through your bower configuration. It is possible you may have a `.bowerrc`-file that applies global configuration in your `~` (home) or `/` (root) directory.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem so I would like to let here my experience on this.

### Solution

1. Deleted the Bower cache.
2. Reinstall Git, it seems that when I install a new version of Xcode I needed agreed with license, so when I ran the command Git, I agreed with license.
3. Once again I ran "yo polymer"

And that's all, everything running!

Thank you all for your advices on this